# How to return values from "upsert" query in case when UPDATE has been performed?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, upsert

```
WITH upsert AS (UPDATE tbl SET a = 2 WHERE a = 1 RETURNING tbl.*)
INSERT INTO tbl (a)
SELECT 1 WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT * FROM upsert )
RETURNING *
```

This "upsert" statement works however I would like to retrieve either UPDATE or INSERTED values. When upsert performs `INSERT` (row is not yet in db) then inserted values are returned correctly returned from query.

However when `UPDATE` is performed then no values are returned (but row IS updated). I've tried adding `RETURNING upsert.*` but it yelds error `missing FROM-clause entry for table \"upsert\"`.

Comment: In Postgres 9.5 or later, use UPSERT (`INSERT ... ON CONFLICT ... DO UPDATE`) for this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40880200/939860

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use a second CTE for the INSERT:

```
WITH upsert AS (
  UPDATE tbl SET a = 2 
  WHERE a = 1 
  RETURNING tbl.*
), inserted AS (
  INSERT INTO tbl (a)
  SELECT 1 WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT * FROM upsert )
  RETURNING *
)
select *
from upsert
union all
select * 
from inserted
```